# ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED？？？

Tags: django, testing, selenium, windows-7

**When I test django by the selenium, the message "ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED" can be found。Smoetimes it's**

```
[6952:4828:0813/120624:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "d:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "d:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "d:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 192, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "d:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "d:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 981, in _h
andle_request_noblock
     self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
     self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
     self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 139
, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
     self.finish()
   File "d:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
   File "d:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053]
.[4828:7168:0813/120645:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
 [4916:6692:0813/120647:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 48.504s

OK
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
----------------------------------------`
```

**but othertime it's**

```
[7292:6276:0813/120013:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[7172:7500:0813/120022:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(132)] pipe error: 109
.[7500:3040:0813/120036:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 47.570s

OK
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Comment: The project is https://github.com/hackrole/django-TDD